# PX4: Obsolete PX4 Toolchain PIP packages in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pip, px4

I am staring with PX4, and I unsuccessfully tried to install PX4 on the latest Debian or Mint (I even edited the installer bash script they rpovide, to use the proper distro version name, but it always failed something).

Later, as [their official guide recommends Ubuntu **18.04** or **20.04**](https://docs.px4.io/v1.12/en/dev_setup/dev_env_linux_ubuntu.html), I ended up installing that flavour, 20.04 version, and, though their installer, it is how I made it "work" without loosing too much time.

The issue is that Ubuntu has nowadays a lot of inconveniences, and not just Canonical's Snap, but also, 20.04 comes with an obsolete Python version (3.8.10, and, on another job, 1 year ago, once we upgraded it using alternative PPA repos, [it broke the system, Apt actually, which seems dependent on 3.8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652299/changing-pythons-default-version-breaks-ubuntu-20-04)), and **some Python packages are obsolete as well, for example, mavsdk** (MAVSDK-Python)...
I just upgraded to the last available version on the official repos, upgraded pip, all packages, but I still get **mavsdk 1.4.9**, when the version 2.1 is already available, indeed, 2.x it is the one I need.

Please, does someone know how to update these packages without breaking the OS and without using Virtual Environments (to avoid dealing with different tools integration: Gazebo, JMAVSim, QGroundControl, maybe some of these tools relying on the installed mavsdk version), or, alternatively, an approachable guide about how to install the Dev Toolchain on a more open, standard and updated Linux flavour, such as Debian or Mint?
Other flavours, as Arch, would be also an option.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [the GNU/Linux's PIP wheel is missing](https://discuss.px4.io/t/obsolete-px4-toolchain-pip-packages-in-ubuntu-20-04/36712/3), due to an [issue in the CI/CD workflow](https://github.com/mavlink/MAVSDK-Python/actions/runs/7717854443/job/21037860914), so, these packages are actually missing for real...

The only solution is to report to them (which I did) and wait it to be solved, and working on an alternative platform meanwhile (macOS's MAVSDK is published and works well).